Electric dryer - Venting Clothes Lint to a Bucket?
My electric dryer is in an awkward place in my house.
I'm not in a position to drill through walls for an outdoor vent.
Can a bucket like this be a solution (at least temporary) to vent clothes lint?
How do I prevent fire hazard?
What about humidity?


A dryer vent to the outside is mainly to remove humidity from the dryer from going into the house.  The dryer should have have a lint trap(should be cleaned often) to keep most of the lint from the vent

Is there a window close by, that the vent can be push through?

I can attest that this sort of device will result in a tremendous increase in humidity in the house. Cooler surfaces will condense and drip, steel surfaces will rust. The freezer will begin to accumulate more ice than it can clear with automatic defrost.

is this a condensing dryer?

The obvious answer would be to get a condensing/ventless dryer, but that of course costs more than a bucket.

thanks for providing some insight @fred_dot_u i have a window nearby. I can also use a dehumidifier. Would this be a livable situation in this case?

Consider a test that involves weighing a representative piece of clothing when removed from the washer, then when removed from the dryer. This will tell you a weight over time reference, at eight pounds per gallon of water. Will the dehumidifier remove water at the rate measured during the test? Open window with airflow out of the house would be useful, especially if you have another one elsewhere in the house for entry airflow.

"Not in a position to drill through walls" makes it sound like you're renting.  Is the landlord happy to have all that water constantly pumped onto their walls, windows, doors, floors & ceiling?   They might very quickly come around when faced with the costs of not doing so.

As there is a window nearby, they have inexpensive pre-made window dryer vents. They install into the window in an easily reversible fashion, and provide a standard dryer flapper. As long as you don't have casement windows, the moisture problem is solved.

The bucket simply will not work.  I mean what you're making is a bubbler/suppression pool, like BWR nuclear reactors have.  A dryer typically uses 4 kWH = 13,600 scientific BTU (1 BTU raises 1 pound of water 1 degree F).  To avoid splash-out, that bucket can't be filled more than 3 gallons, so 25 lbs of water.  13,600 into 25 = each pound suppresses 540 BTU, which raises it 1 degree F remember. That would raise it from 70F past 212F where it will boil.  So you'll simply overwhelm it.   30 gallons (250#), each pound suppressing 54 BTU, would work. Get a 55 gallon drum.


how do i prevent fire hazard?

There should be no fire hazard related to use of a water-catch lint bucket, assuming the dryer was originally installed and is maintained and operated according to manufacturer's instructions.

what about Humidity?

Humidity that would normally be exhausted to the outside will now be inside your home instead. Whether or not this will be an issue for you depends on your tolerance for that, and other factors like how well your house is ventilated and whether you run an AC unit or dehumidifier.

@crip659 if you're in the sort of climate where low humidity is a problem, yes. Round here (mild, damp winters) it would just lead to walls running with condensation and mould everywhere. Since you wrote that the OP mentioned a dehumidifer, suggesting a climate more like mine than yours

Terrible idea - the humidity will be more destructive than you realize, and necessitate costly house repairs and upkeep. Peeling paint, mold, and possible wood rot. Condensate will get into places you didn't expect.  Been there lived that.
The better answer here is a different type of dryer that does not need venting at all, while saving a lot of money operationally both on less electricity and less heating or A/C needed. They are called "heat pump dryers". Here is a Technology Connections video segment on the topic.
Oh, and many models run on normal 120V and can share the dual socket with the washing machine. They take very little power.  (some use 240V, so don't pick those).  As such, they are "Swiss Army knives" for difficult locations.  Some don't even need a drain, and can capture the condensate in a bucket built into the machine like a dehumidifier.

If  you will be installing this next to a washing machine, there should be a drain available, though sharing it with the washer may take a bit of work.

Even condensing dryers are better than trying to rig a condensing bucket of some sort. They need more power than a heat pump, and do release a little humidity, but they capture most of it and are much cheaper. These days a tight budget is the only reason to not choose a heat pump model. Not sure about where you are, but here we also have washer dryers. These take no extra space, power connections, or drains, but are less efficient - an option if you only need to use it occasionally

@ChrisH However condensing dryers are quite slow and may be dissatisfactory to Americans used to "dry clothes by literally boiling the water out with 4 kWH of energy" dryers.  The bucket won't work as a suppression pool, because it's way too small. Do the math. 4 kWH = 13600 BTU.  Into 3 gallons of water (25 lbs) that's 544 BTU/lb  Nominally raising its temperature by 544F.  It would need to be more like 30 gallons so each pound of water suppresses 54 BTU.

@Harper-ReinstateMonica I agree the bucket is useless (even a bigger bucket and industrial quantities of ice would be a science experiment rather than a practical appliance) but the condenser I used to have was only slightly slower than a (3kW electric) vented dryer - say 2hrs rather than 1.5. The main thing I had against it was the energy consumption, but the heat and moisture into the house were other negatives. Washer dryers use cold tap water as their cooling, wasting heat and water down the drain, but save space - probably more use in smaller British houses than bigger American ones

@ChrisH and you're SURE it wasn't a heat pump dryer?  That performance ratio (4:3) matches heat pump dryers pretty closely based on this   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nh-j0sWBEJA ... the ice would do "something" for you since you'd benefit from its latent heat of fusion (160? BTU/lb).

@Harper-ReinstateMonica I don't think heat pump ones were even available when we got it, certainly not at our budget. But electric dryers are normal here and we get 3kW from a normal socket, so it's a different context. The few gas dryers I've used seem like a very fast way to ruin clothes (usually shrinking T-shirts). Yes, plentiful ice would make that bucket thing just about work - mainly latent heat but also extra cold and more surface area  so the exhaust is dried much better
